# Insert xml element contents(which is also xml tags) into column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

For a table schema like below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [EmployeeId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Skills] [xml] NOT NULL,
    [Projects] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

When inserting data into table, i want to insert only child tags of `<SkillSet>` but seems `<SkillSet>` along with it's child elements inserts into Skill xml columns.

```
declare @doc NVARCHAR(MAX)

declare @idoc INT

select @doc = '<Request Type="InsertEmployee" CRUD="C">
    <Employee>
      <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
      <Name>Deeptechtons</Name>
      <Location>USA</Location>
        <SkillSet>
        <Skill>C#</Skill>
        <Skill>SQL Server 2005</Skill>
        <Skill>ASP.net</Skill>
        </SkillSet>
      <Projects>
        <Project>LowBin</Project>
        <Project>Maskin</Project>
      </Projects>
    </Employee>
  </Request>'

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output,@doc

insert into Employee (
                        EmployeeId
                        ,[Name]
                        ,Location
                        ,Skills,
                        Projects
                     )
            SELECT      NEWID()
                        ,[Name]
                        ,Location
                        ,Skills
                        ,Projects
            FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'Request/Employee',2)
            WITH
                    (
                        [Name] NVARCHAR(50)
                        ,Location   NVARCHAR(50)
                        ,Skills XML 'SkillSet'
                        ,Projects NVARCHAR(400)
                    )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

#### Questions

- How to insert only child elements of `<Skillset>` rather than whole tag and its children.
- I expected `Projects` also to be inserted same as  did but only `Lowbin` content of first Project tag is inserted. Can you correct my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on SQL Server 2005 you can make use of the XML data type and do like this instead.

```
declare @doc xml

select @doc = '<Request Type="InsertEmployee" CRUD="C">
    <Employee>
      <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
      <Name>Deeptechtons</Name>
      <Location>USA</Location>
        <SkillSet>
        <Skill>C#</Skill>
        <Skill>SQL Server 2005</Skill>
        <Skill>ASP.net</Skill>
        </SkillSet>
      <Projects>
        <Project>LowBin</Project>
        <Project>Maskin</Project>
      </Projects>
    </Employee>
  </Request>'

insert into Employee (
                        EmployeeId
                        ,[Name]
                        ,Location
                        ,Skills,
                        Projects
                     )
select newid(),
       T.N.value('Name[1]',  'nvarchar(50)'),
       T.N.value('Location[1]',  'nvarchar(50)'),
       T.N.query('SkillSet/*'),
       cast(T.N.query('Projects/*') as nvarchar(400))
from @doc.nodes('/Request/Employee') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
BC76E37C-0C0D-4B7B-92FD-0F7807F9204B 
Deeptechtons 
USA 
<Skill>C#</Skill><Skill>SQL Server005</Skill>Skill>ASP.net</Skill>
<Project>LowBin</Project><Project>Maskin</Project>
```

**Update:**

If you really want to use OPENXML for some reason you can use this.

```
insert into Employee (
                        EmployeeId
                        ,[Name]
                        ,Location
                        ,Skills,
                        Projects
                     )
            SELECT      NEWID()
                        ,[Name]
                        ,Location
                        ,Skills.query('SkillSet/*')
                        ,cast(Projects.query('Projects/*') as nvarchar(max))
            FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'Request/Employee',2)
            WITH
                    (
                        [Name] NVARCHAR(50)
                        ,Location   NVARCHAR(50)
                        ,Skills XML 'SkillSet'
                        ,Projects XML
                    )
```

Comment: do i  get to  lose anything by declaring `@doc` to be xml datatype, also could u provide a reference to `T(N)` what does it mean how does it work

Comment: @Deeptechtoons The output is the same but there might be a difference in performance. Might be faster or slower but it is much easier to do what you want. Nodes() shreds the XML into rows and T is the table alias that holds the shredded XML and N is the column name. You can just name them whatever you like.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but i think you are right man who can answer this well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740826/tsql-how-to-select-employee-with-skills-in-xml-column